# Multiplying matrices such that their product "commutes"

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

> Let $f,g:\mathbb{R\to R}$ be analytic functions and consider the matrix $$A(x)=\begin{pmatrix}f(x)&g(x)\\1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$ Assume $f(x)\neq g(x)$ at every point $x\in\mathbb R$. Give an example for a non-singular matrix $B(x)$ for which $$A(x)B(y)-A(y)B(x)=0.$$

I tried writing $B(x)=\begin{pmatrix}a(x)&b(x)\\c(x)&d(x)\end{pmatrix}$ explicitly and solving the equations but it just seems too complicated. Is there any other way to find such $B$?

Comment: Hint: in order for two matrices to commute they must share eigenvectors.  What are the eigenvectors of $A$?

Comment: @DanUznanski What two matrices commute?

Comment: Nobody said anything about eigen**values**.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I'm not sure what your complaint here is

Comment: $A(x) B(y) - A(y) B(x) = 0$ is an equation involving four different matrices.  There is no commuting here.

Comment: So the title is rather misleading, since there's some "commuting" there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson changed the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example is 
$$ A(x) = \pmatrix{1 & g(x)\cr 1 & 0\cr},\ B(x) = \pmatrix{a & b\cr c g(x) & d g(x)\cr}$$
where $ad - bc \ne 0$, and $g(x) \ne 1$.

Comment: Altohugh the question asked for "a way" to find $B(x)$, not for an example of $B(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! If we demand that $f$ is not constant as well, can one still come with an example? Also: How did you find this example?